# Understanding Python 3 matplotlib.plot.cohere and scipy.signal.coherence functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting some weird results using these coherence codes in Python 3.7.3.

So, if I understand it correctly, if two signals have the same frequency and amplitude, but are phased, coherence between them should be 1 (100%). To test this, I've written some code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal as sig

samp = 1000 
freq = 5
x = np.arange(samp)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*x/samp) # first signal
y2 = np.cos(2*np.pi*freq*x/samp) # second signal, phased .5 pi radians

# First attempt at testing coherence:

ff, Cxy = sig.coherence(y, y2)
plt.semilogy(ff, Cxy)
plt.show()
```

This gives me a plot that shows coherence of ~1 at frequency 0, and at frequency 0.5, with lower values of coherence in between.

[image: First plot]

Then I tried this:

```
plt.cohere(y, y2)
plt.show()
```

And it gives me a plot with coherence of 1 at ~ frequency 0, 0.5, and 1, with lower coherence in between.

[image: Second plot]

OK, so, how do I interpret this now? My goal is to use this as a measure of coherence in certain frequency bins, e.g., 1-5 Hz, 5-12 Hz, etc... I am assuming that for that purpose I'd average the coherence coefficients for each data point in between those frequency boundaries. However, I don't understand why I'm getting an output between 0-0.5 and 0-1.0 for my coherence values, if the signal frequency is 5. Does that mean that I should be multiplying the graph's frequency axis by my signal frequency? I'd greatly appreciate some help understanding this output better.

Comment: cohere takes a sampling frequency argument `Fs` to help you scale `ff`.  Two signals with no power at a given frequency will not be coherent, so you only expect coherence of 1 near your signal's frequency.    You may want to consider adding some random noise to your sine waves to see this more realistically.

Comment: Thank you, Jody. That clarified the plt.cohere() function. It makes sense now.